# All The King's Men-Selfmate In 14 Moves?

Tags: chess, selfmate

I call this "All The King's Men" because lots of White's pieces are needed in this selfmate. It was somewhat of an accident actually, but it is still a pretty position in my opinion.

It's White to move and the goal here is to [selfmate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfmate) themselves in 14 moves. Naturally, Black tries to prolong their resistance for as long as possible.

[image]

Comment: No preview image of the board?

Comment: Not last night, an hour ago. [This](https://www.apronus.com/chess/pgnviewer/?p=A_BKRRN_Q____________P________P___P____P_N____B_Pp___PkPP______rb0w&m=hxg8ZQ*_Kxg8_gxh8ZR*_Kf7_Qh5*_Ke6_Nb4_a6_b6_a5_Nc2_a4_e8ZB_a3_Bf7*_Kf5_Bfa2_Ke4_Nd2*_Kd3_Be7_Kc3_b7_Kd3_b8ZQ_Kc3_Qb2*_axb2M&n=27) is [their](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57057/arnaud-mortier) solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one of the solutions to the puzzle. This should show a clear idea for the strategy.

> 1. hxg8=Q+ Kxg8 2. gxh8=Q+  Kf7 3. e8=B+ Ke6 4. Rd6+ Kxd6 5. Qh3 Kd5 6. Qd7+ Kc4 7. Be7 Kb3 8. Qa1 Kc4 9. Qa4+ Kc3 10. b6 axb6 11. Rd1 b5 12. Qa2 b4 13. h7 b3 14. Qa4 b2#
> [image]